# How does Facebook Credits deal with refunds/chargebacks and my Callback-URL?

Tags: facebook, callback, credits

I try to handle chargebacks / refunds of Facebook Credits.

But I can't determine from the documentation whether Facebook will call my callback-URL if a chargeback occurs. Does anybody have experience with chargebacks? Do they call it with status "refunded"?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a number of Chargebacks in my application, and none of them have called my callback page. They are only mentioned in the daily credit reports. However, I have had FB issue refunds, and it called the callback page as expected.

I do find it extremely odd however that Facebook does not keep track of CHARGEBACKS or REFUNDS directly in their own order info returns. When I query the graph for application payments (https://graph.facebook.com/appid/payments?access_token=...), I get no REFUNDED or CHARGEBACK statuses! Anyway, you can find more in-depth info at this location:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/disputes/